# Migrating address book (with folders) from Outlook Express to Outlook

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, contacts

I am trying to get an address book from Outlook Express to Outlook. I have access to each version of Outlook from 2007-2013, as well as Outlook Express 6. The address book is formatted with folders and must be migrated that way -- manually redoing the folder structure is not an option.

I tried simply importing using Outlook 2007 (`File --> Import and Export --> Import Internet Mail and Addresses --> Outlook Express`), but it comes back with a box that says "0 of 0 addresses imported. 0 of 0 distribution lists imported."

The original installation and Outlook 2007 are on an XP SP3 machine, and 2010/2013 can be installed on a separate W7 machine if needed.

What options do I have to complete this process?

Answer (score 0):

At http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196215
Microsoft says:

**Drag Address Information to Outlook**

- It is possible to move individual or groups of WAB entries to Outlook by dragging them. To do this, follow these steps:
- On the Start menu, point to Find, and then click Files And Folders. In the Open box type *.wab, and then click OK. Double-click the WAB file from which you wish to move addresses.
- Open Outlook if it is not already open.
- Resize Outlook so that the WAB and Outlook are visible next to each other on the screen. Ensure that the Outlook Contacts folder is visible in the resized Outlook window.
- Select an entry from the WAB. Drag it to the Contacts folder. A new Outlook Contact form will be created with the information from the WAB entry. Click Save and close.

NOTE: Press SHIFT and select contiguous groups of entries or press CTRL and select non-contiguous entries. You may want to do this for selected Contacts or small groups.

To the best of my recollection, using export/import between OE and Outlook 2007/2010 won't retain the groups.  However, I think if you export to something 3rd-party with the capability, perhaps gmail, and then import from there to Outlook, your groups might also be retained.

An alternative is to use an older version of Outlook that still was able to use the WAB that Outlook Express uses.